# XML Digital Signature Java

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, sha256

i need to digital sign my XML messages in JAVA:
The resulting XML signature should have the following format:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<DigestValue>DsP5NLca+plhp9tZvGwykfb2whQYt3CQ5sbsVd9Q9aE=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
LrfE0po3YPvVxB/m77iBWWiR07Ghiuhuj7tO2C2LKqZK2cLrAiidt+3tjbJ3m16quCFxfh7bmjRtJsGi7a3HKtK
qY4auqrjNB62AtYrxvm+7Qd/cRacom4e3M9uF9JD1zTfoGun9w4WDfDrDaoZ+ZwUgNtf6sTYO5Ctcj5sYcD0=
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyName>7D665C81ABBE1A7D0E525BFC171F04D276F07BF2</KeyName>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

Can anyone provide some help with code ??

Edit:

i came up with this code :

```
private static Document sign(Document doc) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException,
            FileNotFoundException, TransformerException {

        String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");

        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

        Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null));

        // Create the SignedInfo
        SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(
                fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(512);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(kp.getPublic());

        KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv));

        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(kp.getPrivate(), doc.getDocumentElement());

        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
        signature.sign(dsc);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("mySignedFile")));

        return doc;
    }
```

but the Problem is i am getting :

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
```

and not :

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution:

i find it on this link
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/santuario-dev/200907.mbox/%3C4A704241.9060806@sun.com%3E
the problem was RSA-SHA256 Algorithm :

here is the resulting code :

```
private static Document sign(Document doc) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyException, MarshalException, XMLSignatureException,
            FileNotFoundException, TransformerException {

        String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");

        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

        DigestMethod digestMethod = fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null);
        Transform transform = fac.newTransform(ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null);
        Reference reference = fac.newReference("", digestMethod, singletonList(transform), null, null);
        SignatureMethod signatureMethod = fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null);
        CanonicalizationMethod canonicalizationMethod = fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(EXCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);

        // Create the SignedInfo
        SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(canonicalizationMethod, signatureMethod, singletonList(reference));


        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(2048);

        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(kp.getPublic());

        // Create a KeyInfo and add the KeyValue to it
        KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv));
        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(kp.getPrivate(), doc.getDocumentElement());

        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
        signature.sign(dsc);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();

        // output the resulting document
        OutputStream os;

        os = new FileOutputStream("xmlOut.xml");

        trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
        return doc;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You got `<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>`, because that's what you asked for: `fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null)`.
As you figured out and https://blogs.oracle.com/mullan/entry/using_stronger_xml_signature_algorithms states, `fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", (SignatureMethodParameterSpec) null)` will get you `<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />`.

Answer (score 0):

These are standard XML-Signatures. See the [W3 Documentation on "XML-Signature Syntax and Processing"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/PR-xmldsig-core-20010820/) for the specification how this can be done. A quick search on google lead to this howto written by Oracle on the integration of XML Signatures in Java: [XML Digital Signature API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html). If you have any further problems, please shows us what you have tried.