# ResourceResolverException while signing an XML

Tags: java, xml, x509

I'm desperately trying to sign an XML document with a X509 certificate.
I have to sign multiple elements in my document, so I'm giving a List of Reference to my SignedInfo.

The problem I'm facing occurs at the signature itself. I receive an exception saying that it cannot resolve an element with the ID I provide.

While researching to find a solution, I stumbled upon this ticket (which is a bug of OpenJDK 1.7) : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8017171

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8 and still have the problem.

### **Code** :

```java
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(unsignedXml));

List<Reference> refs = new ArrayList<Reference>();
refs.add(fac.newReference(
        "#TS",
        fac.newDigestMethod("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1", null),
        Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#",(TransformParameterSpec) null)),
        null, null));

SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(
        fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
                (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
        fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1", null),
        refs);

FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(input, password.toCharArray());
Key key = ks.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
    Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    keyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
}

KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(keyPair.getPublic());
KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv));

DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyPair.getPrivate(), doc.getDocumentElement());

XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

signature.sign(dsc);

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(signedXml);
```

### **Exception** :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID TS
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:431)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.digest(DOMReference.java:359)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.digestReference(DOMXMLSignature.java:496)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:379)
    at testsig.testsig.Signature.sign(Signature.java:131)
    at testsig.testsig.App.main(App.java:32)
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID TS
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:134)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:425)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID TS
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment.engineResolveURI(ResolverFragment.java:89)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.resolve(ResourceResolver.java:313)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:126)
    ... 6 more
javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID TS
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:134)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:425)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.digest(DOMReference.java:359)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.digestReference(DOMXMLSignature.java:496)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:379)
    at testsig.testsig.Signature.sign(Signature.java:131)
    at testsig.testsig.App.main(App.java:32)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID TS
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.implementations.ResolverFragment.engineResolveURI(ResolverFragment.java:89)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver.resolve(ResourceResolver.java:313)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:126)
    ... 6 more
```

My problem could be solved with at least one answer to those following questions :
Is there a workaround ?
Is there an other way of signing XML files ?

Regards

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528667/xml-digital-signature-java

Comment: @Sambit Tanks for your comment. Unforunately, this help as the topic is a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding more a work around than a solution. The idea is to get the Element I need with XMLHelper using the DOM, getting the ID Attr from the element. Then I add the attribute with setIdAttributeNode() to my Element.
When manipulating the Element that way, no Exception is thrown when adding a new Reference to the XMLSignatureFactory.

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("wsu:Timestamp");
    Node node = list.item(0);
    Element tempEl = XMLHelper.getChildElementsByTagName(doc.getDocumentElement(), "Header").get(0);
    Element securityElement = XMLHelper.getChildElementsByTagName(tempEl, "Security").get(0);

    tempEl = XMLHelper.getChildElementsByTagName(securityElement, "Assertion").get(0);
    Attr attr = (Attr)tempEl.getAttributes().getNamedItem("AssertionID");
    tempEl.setIdAttributeNode(attr, true);
    String ref = "#" + attr.getValue();

    List<Reference> refs = new ArrayList<Reference>();
    refs.add(fac.newReference(
            ref,
            fac.newDigestMethod("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1", null),
            Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#",(TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null,
            null));
```

This is not an ideal solution in my opinion as it is too much related to the DOM of the XML. But I suppose that was the only solution I could find to make it work and go around the known bug within the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Error came when sign the document.
After a lot of research, I found the solution.
**Before sign the document** <signature.sign(dsc);> **setURIDereferencer** **to empty** like the below code sample

```
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyPair.getPrivateKey(), 
    document.getDocumentElement());

    dsc.setURIDereferencer(new EmptyURIDereferencer(document));
```

And write below code the same file as the inner class

```
class EmptyURIDereferencer implements URIDereferencer {

private Node data = null;

public EmptyURIDereferencer(Node node) {

    data = node;
}

public Data dereference(URIReference ref, XMLCryptoContext ctxt) {

    return new NodeSetData() {
        public Iterator iterator() {

            return Collections.singletonList(data).iterator();
        }
    };
}
```

}