# How to solve the diffenece of originaldata when enveloping xml signature between sign and verify?

Tags: java, xml

```
            DigestMethod sm3DigMethod = fac.newDigestMethod(DOMDigestMethod.SM3, null);


            
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            Document signatureDoc = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            XMLStructure content = new DOMStructure(signatureDoc.getDocumentElement());
            XMLObject obj = fac.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(content), "object", (String) null, (String) null);

            
            CanonicalizationMethod c14nWithCommentMethod =
                    fac.newCanonicalizationMethod("http://127.0.0.1/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments", (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);
            
            SignatureMethod sm2_sm3SigMethod = fac.newSignatureMethod(DOMSignatureMethod.SM2_SM3, null);
            
            SignedInfo signedInfo = fac.newSignedInfo(c14nWithCommentMethod, sm2_sm3SigMethod, Collections.singletonList(refToRootDoc));

            KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFac = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
            KeyValue keyValue = keyInfoFac.newKeyValue(publicKey);
            KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFac.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(keyValue));
            
            XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo, Collections.singletonList(obj), null, null);


            DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, signatureDoc);

            
            signature.sign(dsc);
```

When signing: original data is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0qef.png)

when verifing: original data is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuPZb.png)

I feel like there is a problem with the code in the signature section,hope it can be signed using the actual original text. What do I need to do

Comment: Why are you using object instead of book? XMLObject obj = fac.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(content), "object", (String) null, (String) null);

Comment: @jdweng
This should include or not replace. It seem like the syntax of enveloping xml signature.

Comment: See following : https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/dig-signature-api.html or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528667/xml-digital-signature-java